# C++ If Statement or Text File

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm giving the following

```
Basepay = 800; Job_class = 2; Ed = 3;
Basepay = 800; Job_class = 3; Ed = 1;
```

Now for this program, Job_class and Ed are 1-3. If Job_class is 1, add 10% to the basepay. If it is 2, add 15% to the basepay. If it is 3, add 20% to the basepay.
For education, if Ed is 1, add 5% to the basepay, if it's 2 add 10% and if it's 3 add 15%.

I'm given the input data already. My question is: would it be easier to do this in a if statement or would it be easier to do it via a text file?

Also, can someone show me an example? I'd normally do the following

```
cout << "Please enter a Job Class"
cin >> Job_class
if (Job_class == 1)
    basepay = basepay + basepay*.10;
```

Does that look correct?

Comment: There are quite a number of ways to do this, your way works fine if that's how you would like to do it. Some possible methods are: if statements, switch cases, maps, etc.

Comment: I'm not really sure I got your question, but yes, that looks fine.

Comment: Careful with those brackets/parentheses by the way...

Comment: And with float precision and indentation

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use switch in this case. For example

```
     switch(Job_class)
     {
       case 1 : basepay = basepay + basepay *.10;
                break;

       case 2 : basepay = basepay + basepay *.15;
                break;

       case 3 : basepay = basepay + basepay *.20;
                break;
     }
```

Comment: How does the program know what is entered for Job_class then though?

Comment: @user3404737 This solution is only replacing the `if` statement, not whole code.

Comment: User will enter Job_Class as input and same can be used in switch.

Comment: IF you already have all the input data then you can make a map(key, value) where your key can be about whom this information belongs could be ID or NAME and value will be an object holding information about base pay, job_class, Ed etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `if` statements completely.

```
Basepay = Basepay + (0.05 * Basepay)
           + (Job_Class * 0.05 * Basepay) + (Ed * 0.05 * Basepay);
```

which equals

```
Basepay = Basepay + (0.05 * Basepay) * (Job_Class + Ed);
```

which also equals

```
Basepay += (0.05 * Basepay) * (Job_Class + Ed);
```

Now, I'm not 100 % positive if my math was correct, but what I'm trying to say - If there's a way to come up with a formula, it's usually better than `if` statements. Not in simple programs like this, but in large complex applications it might save you a lot of processor time.

Comment: "it might save you a lot of processor time." -> get it working, get it right. If performance is slow, find out what is slow, and fix that. Right and Easy to read should be a first priority.

Comment: If I were a troll I would point out that you would actually save pipeline stalls… Good thing I am not a troll.

Comment: How would I avoid the if statements though. For example, in one instance Job_class will be adding 5% interest. In another, it may have to add 10% interest depending on the Classification of the input.

Comment: @user3404737 Yes, then you would need conditions indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are wondering if it's better to read "Job Class" from a text file or prompt for user input, is that right? I'd say it depends on the nature of your app, if yours is an interactive app, prompting the user for input is the best way, but if your's is not an interactive app, then I'd say your choice should be dictated by the number of "Job Class" inputs your app will deal with--if you are dealing with 100s of inputs, inputting them will be tedious, reading these inputs from a file will be the best approach.

Code-wise, your code that prompts user for input and reads user response looks okay, but it's error prone, if the user input isn't valid "Job Class" say the user enters a floating point number, or a bunch of characters your code's behavior will be undefined. Instead of cin, consider reading input as a string using getline() and then feed the string to istringstream and then extract the input you are looking for from the istringstream object

```
int getJobClass()
{
   int Job_Class;
   string input;
   bool inputValid = false;
   while(!inputValid)
   {
      cout << "Please Enter Job Class";
      getline(cin, input);
      istringstream inputParser(input);
      if (!(inputParser >> Job_Class))
      {
         cout << "Invalid Job Class Input!" <<endl;
         inputValid = false;
      }
      else
      {
         inputValid = true;
      }
   }
   return Job_Class;
}
```

Once the above is in place, for computing "base pay", you could do something like this:

```
float getPayMultiplier(int Job_class)
{
   float multiplier = 1;
   switch (Job_class)
   {
     case 1:
        multiplier = 0.10;
        break;
     case 2:
        multiplier = 0.15;
        break;
     case 3:
        multiplier = 0.20;
        break;
     default:
        cout << "Invalid Job_Class" << endl;
        break;
    }
    return multiplier;
}

float computeBasePay(float pay)
{
   return pay + (pay * getPayMultiplier(getJobClass()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3404737: Why do you want to avoid `if`? The logic in your code is conditional by nature: base pay (or more precisely pay multiplier) is determined by the job class. Given that, why would you want to avoid using an `if` condition?

If your concerned about code looking bad with too many conditionals, use a `switch...case` If your app is going to have 100s of "Job Class" classifications (which, I doubt you will) then I suggest you construct a `map<int, float>` where your keys are "Job Class" and values are "pay multipliers" that way you do a quick lookup when it's time to compute base-pay, instead of running through 100s of conditionals.